# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined using sendMessage function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want my bot in a certain server to send a dm to a random member every 10 minutes. And when my bot has sent everyone from the server a dm it sends a complete message.

But when I start my bot he says this error code: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(botconfig.prefix + 'dmall')) {
    console.log("demo");
    var list = message.guild.members;
    sendMessage(list);
  }
});


function sendMessage(list) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list.length);
    }

    console.log("I'm done, mate!");
    sendMessage();
  }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

```
CONSOLE: 
demo
4 (is the amount of the members)
4
4
4
for (i = 0; i < list.length i++) {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Does it log `"I am done, mate!"` ?

Comment: yes, but it says Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: What does `list[i]` log?

Comment: the amount of members in a server

Comment: Okay. You are not passing the `list` argument the second time you are calling `sendMessage()`. It should be `sendMessage(list)` after `console.log("I'm done, mate!")`

Comment: Ok it's now working Thanks! But why does it sends 4 times the amount of the members?

Comment: See my answer. I would suggest creating a new question for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the `list` argument the second time you call `sendMessage` function.

```
function sendMessage(list) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list.length);
    }

    console.log("I'm done, mate!");
    sendMessage(list); // Added this
  }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: It's now working Thanks! But why does it sends 4 times the amount of members?

Comment: @MoadTouhafi I would kindly suggest to create a new question for your query. You can share the link (for the new question) here.

Comment: @MoadTouhafi Also, if my answer satisfied your query, do you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: How do you that?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)